# Foreach Loop Is Not Processing Multiple File Uploads - PHP

Tags: php, loops, file, foreach, upload

I'm trying to get my image uploader to handle multiple files.

In my HTML I have added the array brackets to the name attribute and added the multiple attribute:

**HTML**

`<input id="standard-upload-files" type="file" name="standard-upload-files[]" multiple>`

**PHP**

I've reduced the code down, but the images aren't being processed and I'm getting the error message that displays in the `else` part of the code.

Any help as to why the files aren't being processed would be hugely appreciated.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit-images'])) {

    $profileImage = $_POST['submit-images'];

    foreach($_FILES['standard-upload-files']['name'] as $filename) {

        if($_FILES['standard-upload-files']['error'] === 0 ) {

            $temp = $_FILES['standard-upload-files']['tmp_name'];

            // set base time and ID for all images before loop
            $filebase = uniqid() . '_' . time();
                
            // FULL SIZE IMAGE THAT WILL BE DOWNLOADED BY USERS
            move_uploaded_file($temp, "images-download/{$filebase}");

        } else {
            $error[] = "Image failed to load please try again";
        }

    } // foreach

}
```

Comment: `as $filename` -> `as $index => $filemame` - and you should see some errors.  do yourself the luxury to have diagnostic messages visible while developing, e.g. error_reporting and display_errors on your development box. no development box? php has a dev-server, you can with little setup test these thing locally.

Comment: Just as `$_FILES['standard-upload-files']['name']` is an array, `$_FILES['standard-upload-files']['error']` will be too.

Comment: @hakre I do have `error_reporting = E_ALL` and `display_errors = On` in my php.ini file. I changed it to `as $index => $filemame` but I'm having the same issue (with no errors showing apart from my error message that echos out onto the page).

Comment: okay, review the change suggestion. you see what is different? can you imagine for what the introduced variable could be useful? (another person also gave a hint) - and perhaps error_reporting = -1 gives better development experience.

Comment: @hakre Ah. I added `[index]` to the 4th and 5th lines of code after doing `$index => $filename` and it seems to work i.e. `$_FILES['standard-upload-files']['error'][index] === 0` I think I understand now...because `$_FILES` is an associative array the foreach loop must be one as well?

Comment: Yes, and the particular thing is because of `name="standard-upload-files[]"` (the brackets at the end). You find this explained in the PHP manual here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php - specifically for your array case in _Example #3 Uploading array of files_ - once understood, and with foreach and the $index, its straight forward. The whole section has good hints on error handling of file-uploads etc. Get in the know!

Comment: And after you've gained the understanding, try to write down an answer to your question. That also helps to reflect and deepen the learning.